# Will Eevee be a/the new Game Engine?

Tags: rendering, game-engine

Now I haven't gotten into Programing or game making let alone even tried Blender Game but I do have a very basic understanding of game engines and Eevee looks fantastic!! Close if not identical to UE4! I know it will be for the viewport (Super excited)!Thank You in advance!

Comment: I don't think there are any plans yet, I'm fairly sure the BGE has it's own screen drawing code that would also have to be updated to match. The GE is rarely a priority so it may take someone stepping up to do the work.

Comment: If you didn't see it, someone has started to get [evee working with the BGE](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2017-July/048473.html)

Comment: [Here is a video of someone showing BGE with eevee implemented. ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQVEw0gtfaQ)

Answer (score 0):

There has been trials at the links in the comments show, but nothing official yet. Lol I pressed Shift + F on one of my scenes and then it felt amazing...... have fun with that until the official full control gets implemented ;)